# Img having right+bottom padding in ie8

Tags: css, internet-explorer-8

OK so I have positioned images with borders, working fine in ie9 yet in ie8 for some reason the images are slightly padded right+bottom by a few pixels. I've searched for answers for a while now with no results. (If I take away positioning there's no padding)

Here is the img code and a img with class .image

```
img {
border: solid 8px white; 
display: block; 
}

.image {
position: absolute;
top: 580px;
left: 450px;
}
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: If you can recreate the problem on http://jsbin.com/, your question will be easy to solve.

Comment: I solved the q, was a zoom issue, thanks for the tip though!

Comment: @UniAvenger, you can answer it yourself usually and award it as answer, will help future people with a similar problem.

Comment: Oh cool thanks for that, I will keep it in mind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using a CSS reset?  have you tried zeroing out margins & padding to solve this problem:

```
img {
   border: solid 8px white; 
   display: block;
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
}

.image {
   position: absolute;
   top: 580px;
   left: 450px;
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
}
```

Comment: Yeah I tried this, didn't change anything. The .image class would override the margin+padding anyways (putting in just img would have the same result). Thanks anyways.

Comment: You can post a jsfiddle so people can try to solve your problem. Your question is rather abstract and unclear without a proper example

Comment: @UniAvenger, you are saying you ARE using a CSS reset? Why not show it then to be sure, its most likely margins or padding that causes this issue for you then.

Comment: Oh sorry I misread the q, I'm not using a CSS reset currently.

Comment: You deserve a medal, thank you. I added style="display:block;" in the <img> tag and it solved my problem.